# Laravel: one-to-many retrieving single record in view

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I'm currently learning Laravel 5.6. So my problem is this, I have the following Model:

```
class Tour extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'category',
        'overview',
        'activity',
        'exclusion',
        'inclusion',
        'policies',
        'guide_id',
        'province_id'
    ];

    public function tourImages(){
        return $this -> hasMany('App\TourImage');
    }
}

class TourImage extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'path',
        'tour_id'
    ];

    public function tour(){
        return $this -> belongsTo('App\Tour');
    }
}
```

So 1 Tour can have multiple TourImages. What i want to do is that i want to print out all the tours on the index page. But i only want to take one TourImage file to display for each tour. I return only array of all tours from controller. Is there a way that i can retrieve image directly on the blade view without returning more variable from the controller?

Here's what I write for my index method:

```
public function index($province_id = null)
    {
        $tours = Tour::where('province_id', $province_id)->get();
        return view('tours.index', ['tours' => $tours]);
    }
```

Here's my index view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <br/>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Picture</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($tours as $tour)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ $tour->id }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $tour->name }}</td>
                    <td><img src="/storage/{{ $tour->tourImages->path }}" width="200px"/></td>
                    <td>{{ $tour->price }}</td>
                </tr>   
            @endforeach            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass one image of each tour by this code :

```
$tours=Tour::with(['tourImages'=>function($query){ 
    $query->first(); 
}])->get();
```

and in `view`:

```
@foreach($tours as $tour)
    @if ($tour->tourImages->count())
        <img src="/storage/{{ $tour->tourImages[0]->path }}" width="200px"/>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: It will still return collection of tourImages and so it needs to print using `$tour->tourImages[0]->path` in view file.

Comment: I tried this and it says "Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: test with this : `{{$tour->tourImages[0]->path}}` . this code return `one` image in form of `array`

Comment: @AcousticMike . no. it return just  one image

Comment: you're welcome. You can check, only if a tour has a photo. Show it :  `@if ($tour->tourImages->count())
        <img src="/storage/{{ $tour->tourImages->path }}" width="200px"/>
    @endif`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `with()` to get records.like this.

```
$tours = Tour::with('tourImages')->where('province_id', $province_id)->get();
```

Comment: Then what do i write in the view to get path attribute of only 1 TourImage?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new relation in your `Tour` model like

```
public function latestTourImage() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\TourImage')->latest();
}
```

Then you can fetch it using this in your controller file

```
$tours = Tour::with('latestTourImage')->where('province_id', $province_id)->get();
```

and then you can print it in your blade file like

```
$tour->latestTourImage->path
```

Comment: This query passes all the images to `view` and is not optimal. You have to pass one `image` to `view`

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi: how it will pass all the images if its defined with hasOne relation?

Comment: return $this -> hasMany('App\TourImage');

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi: Then you didn't read my answer carefully sir......!!